# Where is the right site for this question?

Tags: discussion, ipad

https://superuser.com/questions/188869/how-do-you-change-file-associations-on-an-ipad-closed

This was closed on both Stackoverflow (which was fair enough), and also superuser.
I would have thought this would be a relevant Superuser question, although it's for an electronic device... not a PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct site is: the  [Apple Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) site.

If it were a PC, Superuser would be the correct place, however as you said, it's not a PC, it's an electronic device.

Comment: Didn't know it existed. Thanks!